# Representing large numbers using linked lists and performing operations

Tags: java, linked-list

I need to store two extremely large numbers (Strings, since they won't fit in int) in two linked lists, add them and then display the result (again, a String).

I can store the numbers directly into the list.

**312312** can be stored as **2->1->3->2->1->3** (actual number will be extremely long)

**111119** can be stored as **9->1->1->1->1->1**

Then I can add them

**11->2->4->3->2->4**

Normally I could do **11*10^0 + 2*10^1 +...+ 4*10^5** and get **423431** but all those operations (multiplication, addition and exponentiation) would again be integer operations and since the actual numbers are going to be extremely big, int or long won't support the operations. The final result has to be a string.

So I need a way to convert 11->2->4->3->2->4 into 423431 without using int. Also, I cannot use BigInteger. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Why can't you use `BigInteger`? Storing numbers as strings is nearly the worst way to handle bigints.

Comment: I am not allowed to. It's a project to implement an Arbitrary Precision Arithmetic Package. I have done all the Infix-Postfix conversions. But to handle big numbers I need this.

Comment: but you need to test if the values are numbers?

Comment: @user2785784, do you require an implementation of "+" or just a way to store an arbitrary number in a linked list?

Comment: No need to test if they're numbers. The inputs are only going to be numbers.

Comment: Actually I require implementation of +, -, * and ^ between two arbitrary numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Well, first thing you need to do is implement carry.**

For each digit (that is >= 10), you need to increase the next digit by that digit `/10` and set that digit to that digit `%10`.

So `11->2->...` becomes `1->3->...`.

**Then to actually produce the string.**

For the most performant option, I suggest `StringBuilder`.

Just `append` each digit in the linked-list, then just `reverse().toString()` (since you started with the smallest number).

Answer (score 1):

Think about how you would do it by hand on paper. If the sum of a pair digits is greater than 9 you write down a carry digit of 1, which you add into the sum of the next pair of digits.

In a computer program you can use a local variable for that: add digits from first and last numbers and the carry from earlier, if sum is greater than.. set carry to 1, else set carry to 0, move on to the next pair...